# javascript - adding DOM view is too slow, need a better way to cache the view once and reuses that for later use

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a view containing of many sub-views, which have relatively heavy CSS properties. and I need to add them(about 10-30 depending on screen-width) to browser every time user changes the sort or the category.

In android we handle this heavy task of adding many views, by using the ListView which basically does the heavy lifting once and then reuses the view later on.

I wanted to know if there is anyway in javascript to cache the view so appending them to the parent would be a lot faster.

in my performance tests, it takes about 500ms to just append the view to the parent DOM. but if there is a way to reuse a cached DOM to make things faster, it would be a lot better.
thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you should make your views simpler?

Comment: that's not possible, but we tried to remove the box shadow and unnecessary subviews, but it doesn't make much of a difference

Comment: How about loading all views and hiding them, then use only show/hide method?

Comment: that's not an option since infinite scrolling is involved

Comment: You might be interested in this article: http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/, by jQuery's mother :-D

Comment: One more possibly interesting article on performance improvements: https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow.

Comment: @wawawared the article was great, if you post it as an answer, I'd vote it up and make it the answer, thanx anyway

Comment: I don't want to make an answer with 2 links that are likely to break in the future. You should better post a detailed answer by yourself about what you've learnt and mark it as accepted, but you can still mention the links as resources :-)

Comment: @wawawared OK great, will do :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88866/discussion-between-wawawared-and-user3425760).

Comment: What a coincidence: http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2015/07/stop_pushing_th.html :-D

Comment: @wawawared wow, that was really awesome, the fact that IE4 had this feature back then really blew my mind. I guess for navigation transition, it's best if we wait and see what future browsers will do.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that in your case, one sub-view is needed at one time. 
So, this library might inspire you http://nexts.github.io/Clusterize.js/
The idea is keep your whole data model in *window* object and render part of it (associated with sub-view) when user sort or category.

Comment: that was a really nice plugin, but my problem is not about larg data sets, its about small data sets with complex views which takes to long to append to view